# ListViewItem selection colors overriding

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I need to override predefined style of the ListViewItem to not have visible selection. I know how to do it if I copy the whole style into my resources and edit it. But I can't believe there is no lighter way than copy-past the whole style.
So I found that default ListViewItem style uses the following brushes for the selection:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note: I've put all those brushes to my UserControl as well as set them all to the yellow color. But I don't have any yellow color in my UI, alas.
So the question is: how can I force the default template to use my overridden brushes?
And second(optional) question: maybe I'm doing it wrong and there is a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vasile said you need to override the brushes, this has to be done on App level, as far as I know you will need to template the whole control if you only want to change one control or on one page.

If you are curious, you can find all the brushes under:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design

To override the listview colors you add this in your App.xaml/resource dictionary, I've added some comments here so you can see which brush does what:

[image]

[image]

```
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">

             <!--After selection - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Yellow"></SolidColorBrush>

             <!--When pointer hovers over an item - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red"></SolidColorBrush>

             <!--When the item is selected (first few milliseconds) - Background-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>

             <!--When the item is selected (first few milliseconds) - Border-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Black"></SolidColorBrush>

        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Thanks, but app wide brush setting is really not an option for me. If there is no other option I will accept it as an answer, though.

Comment: I just had this problem with the settings page, and I found a thread on MSDN where Tim Heuer replied that page-only overriding of brushes is not possible, app.xaml only. The thread was last updated in November. Can't help but think there must be a way..

Answer (score 4):

You have to override them in App.xaml file, something like this (at least that's how I did) :

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

If you need more customization (in my case the ListView items were some pictures), here's a pretty useful link for changing default [Color Controls](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/winappswithcsharp/thread/957b333f-035f-448e-9f4a-213d1290ee51) .

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 Universal App in shared App.xaml I use this code

```
<Application
    x:Class="XXX.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XXX">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying similar things before with no luck. I think you just need to update the entire template.